# Passing a model object to a link generated by a named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my ***routes.rb*** file I have:

`get 'search' => 'movies#search', as: :search_directors`

And the ***search*** action in the ***movies*** controller looks like this:

```
def search
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  # other code
end
```

One of the views contains the following link:

```
= link_to 'Find Movies With Same Director', search_directors_path(@movie)
```

I was hoping that when this link is clicked, the ID of the ***@movie*** object will be available through ***params[:id]*** in the ***movies#search*** action. But instead, when I click on it Rails gives me this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MoviesController#search
>
> Couldn't find Movie with 'id'=

The ***@movie*** object that I'm passing as a parameter to the route IS valid because other parts of the view is working properly (it is the show.html.haml view for the Movie URI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the id in your route, or pass it as an additional parameter (in that case it will be appended to the url as a GET param).

```
get 'search/:id' => 'movies#search', as: :search_directors
```

Or (for GET param):

```
= link_to 'Find Movies With Same Director', search_directors_path(id: @movie.id)
```

In the last case, you would have to add a condition in your search method to test if params[:id] is present at all.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you...

```
def search
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id]) # this will raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if id is not available in data base.

  # you should use where instead of find
  @movie = Movie.where(id: params[:id]).first # this will return nil if not found but not raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Exceptaion.
  # other code
end
```